# Returning multiple results when only one present in DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Alrighty, so this code has been giving me trouble for the past day or so. All of its duties are working perfectly fine, save for the Tax query. (at least thats the only one thats giving me trouble that i can tell of)...
as far as i can tell; the code is giving me trouble because their are multiple TUID and UID's that are the same, but don't go to the same user, (EG an ID that == 1 might be User1 or it might be Group1).

I'm not asking for you guys to fix this code, (It seems everytime i post here, someone says 'oh you just want us to fix your code and blah blah blah blah') I'm just curious if anybody has a good work around for this?

I'm getting duplicate rows returned to the query;
this is what the query returns: http://gmz1023.com/rowline.PNG

```
{
    $sql = "SELECT type FROM bank_transaction LIMIT 25";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam('uid', $uid);
    try{ 
    $que->execute(); 
    ob_start();
    if($que)
    {
        $id = '1';
        $transaction = '';
        while($row = $que->fetch())
        {
        /* This is the tricky bit; for each type that is returned, we start another query and pull up that data.<
        /* This may need to be turned into seperate functions later on. however, for now, keep trying to figure out how to get the code to work, 
        /* There's      nor eason why it shouldn't work, as its simple as hell. and yet we keep getting multiple rows in the table.
            */ 
            if($row[0] == 'govt')
            {
                $sql = "SELECT tuid, uid, balance FROM bank_transaction WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid";
                $querty1 = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $type = 'govt';

                $querty1->bindParam('type', $type);
                $querty1->bindParam('type', $row[0]);
                $querty1->bindParam('uid', $uid);
                try {
                    if($querty1->execute())
                    {
                        $info = $querty1->fetch();
                        $to = parent::getUsername($info[0]);
                        $from = parent::getStoryName($info[1]);
                        $balance = $info[2];
                        $transaction .= "<tr><td>{$id}</td><td>{$from}</td><td>{$to}</td><td>{$balance}</td><td>{$row[0]}</td></tr>";
                        $querty1->closeCursor();
                    }
                }catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}
            }
            if($row[0] == 'business')
            {
                $sql = "SELECT tuid, uid, balance, date FROM bank_transaction WHERE type = :type AND tuid = :uid OR uid = :uid";
                $querty1 = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $type = 'business';
                $querty1->bindParam('type', $type);
                $querty1->bindParam('type', $row[0]);
                $querty1->bindParam('uid', $uid);
                try {
                    if($querty1->execute())
                    {
                        $info = $querty1->fetch();
                        $to = $info[0];
                        $from = $info[1];
                        $balance = $info[2];
                        $date = $info[3];
                        $transaction .= "<tr><td>{$id}</td><td>{$from}</td><td>{$to}</td><td>{$balance}</td><td>{$row[0]}</td><td>{$info[3]}</tr>";
                        $querty1->closeCursor();
                    }
                }catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}
            }
            if($row[0] == 'tax')
            {

                $sql = "SELECT tuid, uid, balance, date FROM bank_transaction WHERE tuid = :tuid AND type = :type ;";
                $querty = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $type = 'tax';
                $uid = '2';
                $querty->bindParam('type', $type);
                $querty->bindParam('tuid', $uid);
                try {
                    if($querty->execute())
                    {
                        $info = $querty->fetch();
                        $to = parent::getStoryName($info[0]);
                        $from = parent::getUsername($info[1]);
                        $balance = $info[2];
                        $transaction .= "<tr><td>{$id}</td><td>{$from}</td><td>{$to}</td><td>{$balance}</td><td>{$row[0]}</td><td>{$info[3]}</tr>";
                        $querty->closeCursor();
                    }
                }catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}

            }
            elseif($row[0] == 'personal')
            {
                $sql = "SELECT tuid, uid, balance FROM bank_transaction WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid OR tuid = :uid";
                $querty = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $type = 'personal';
                $querty->bindParam('type', $type);
                $queryt->bindParam('uid', $uid);
                try {
                    if($querty->execute())
                    {
                        $info = $querty->fetch();
                        $to = $info[0];
                        $from = $info[1];
                        $balance = $info[2];
                        $transaction .= "<tr><td>{$id}</td><td>{$from}</td><td>{$to}</td><td>{$balance}</td><td>{$row[0]}</td></tr>";
                        $querty->closeCursor();
                    }
                }catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}
            }
            $id = $id +1;
        }
    return $transaction;
    ob_end_clean();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR!";
    }
    }catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }  
}
```

The Database
    tid int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
    uid int(11)         No  None
    tuid    int(11)         No  None
    balance int(11)         No  None
    type    enum('personal', 'govt', 'business', 'tax') latin1_swedish_ci       No  date    datetime

Comment: I'm getting duplicate returns from the database; EG every DB entry that has a type of "Tax" returns to my test account. (my test account is UID 2)

Comment: Can you please calirfy with an example of duplicate rows?(update your question) A db-schema of tables involved might be helpful as well.

Comment: added the Db-scheme data and a picture of what's returning

Comment: Added an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The tax query has a semicolon at the end. It's likely that this causing MySQL to throw an error.

---

But the entire code example is bizarre. The displayed `$id` value isn't from the database, it's a loop counter for the rows fetched from first query.

```
SELECT type FROM bank_transaction LIMIT 25
```

For each row returned, a check is performed on the value returned for "`type`", and depending on the value, one of four other queries is executed. The queries are all similar:

**`"govt"`**

```
SELECT tuid
     , uid
     , balance
     , date
  FROM bank_transaction
 WHERE type = :type
   AND tuid = :uid
    OR uid = :uid
```

**`"business"`**

```
SELECT tuid
     , uid
     , balance
     , date
  FROM bank_transaction
 WHERE type = :type
   AND tuid = :uid
    OR uid = :uid
```

**`"tax"`**

```
SELECT tuid
     , uid
     , balance
     , date
  FROM bank_transaction
 WHERE tuid = :tuid
   AND type = :type
```

**`"personal"`**

```
SELECT tuid
     , uid
     , balance
  FROM bank_transaction
 WHERE type = :type
   AND uid = :uid 
    OR tuid = :uid
```

There's some potential problems with the precedence of `AND` and `OR` in some of those queries, and there's also a potential problem with PDO and referencing the same named bind variable more than once (but this "bug" may have been addressed in a more recent version of PDO.)

And the bindParam calls specify the named bind parameter without the leading colon, which is odd. I've never seen that before.

---

I think the bigger issue with the code is that each time through the outermost loop (it does manage to successfully increment the `$id` value each time through). But for each type, it executes an identical SQL statement, with identical bind values. And it's a nearly guaranteed that MySQL is returning the same set of rows, in the same order, each time the query is executed.

But only the first row is fetched and processed.

I apologize if this is blunt, but...

This looks as if someone threw a whole pile of code at the problem, without actually having a good conceptual understanding of what needs to be done, and without thinking through a workable algorithm.

The problems with this code are lot bigger than syntax issues.

The outermost query that gets type from the database doesn't look like it has any purpose, except to limit the number of rows returned. (I'm a little surprised there aren't 25 rows in the result; I can only guess that there are either actually 4 rows in the table, or more likely, that query is returning more than 4 rows, but the fifth row returned has `type='tax'`, which is causing the "tax" query to be executed, which is causing a MySQL syntax error.

This code is not "simple" at all. It's overly complex, and unsurprisingly ineffective.

Comment: It's ok to bind params without leading colons (it's not a strict rule that you have to have it). But my opinion that it is easier with a colon. But I guess that's just a matter of taste. A much well formulated answer with concrete reasons why/why not code is good. Therefore you get +1 from me.

Comment: Yah... i Realize this code sucked; it started off reasonably simple, however after getting error after error with it (and at the time) and not wanting to rewrite it entirely, i just kept tacking things onto it... This whole things boils down to me needing to stop drinking so much coffee and go to bed more regularly.
I've solved the code by inserting the Username into the Database instead of the UID.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GROUP BY to make selection unique:

```
SELECT tuid, uid, balance FROM bank_transaction WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: Adding A GROUP BY to one of the queries is NOT going to fix the problems in this code.

Comment: @spencer7593 - doesn't group by make selection unique based on what is grouped?

Comment: Yes it does. But in the OP code, only one row is being fetched from the resultset returned by that query. The duplicates are not a result of that query, but rather, due to the OP executing that same query four times, and fetching the first row each time. There may be problems in that query, but that's not what's broken.

Comment: @spencer7593 - ah I see. Thanks for mentioning this! :-)